# Why does my IR receiver PCB only work when I touch the sensor pins?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers, pcb-antenna, ir-receiver, qtouch

I have designed a PCB based on a schematic which I am pretty sure that is correct and I have tested the schematic several times on the breadboards and all of them worked properly.

But, after I designed the PCB I found that it only works when I touch the the photo diode pins otherwise it doesn't work normally.

My PCB is only 2 layers and I have not separated (GND,VIRTUAL GND,AND 12V POWER) in to a separated PCB layers.

Also, I have checked all of my OP-AMP voltage and input voltage and compared them with the breadboard, the result was that all of them were same as each other but, I can not understand why PCB doesn't work good and I have to touch the pins to make it  works.

I am new employee in a company and it is very important for them that I fix this issue, I tried a lot to fix this issue but until now I have not succeeded.

So, I will be appreciate if any of you guys can give me an advise or guide me to I be able to fix this or issue design a PCB that works properly.

Finally I have to mentioned that this schematic has been designed by very well known company and is 100 present is correct and good but this design is a little bit old maybe for 12 years ago.

I have uploaded the schematic here.

Thank you everybody for your help and time.

[image]

Comment: Tip: use ground symbols at the components to eliminate the ground nets running all over the page. It reduces clutter and reveals the node potential at a glance. If you have two grounds then use two different ground symbols. Turning off the grid too before taking a screen grab will also help legibility.

Comment: Dividing your schematic into functional sections would also help. As it is it is a mess of connections that is hard to make sense of. It took me a while to realize that you are not actually using the power-supply terminals of your op-amps as additional outputs.

Comment: But,I have used ground symbols for each component. Maybe I misunderstand what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: the schematic is not very good ...... the output stage does not follow convention so it is unclear .... not all power connections follow convention ..... have a look at every component in the schematic .... you will find one that is totally useless ..... just a plain messy schematic

Comment: R21 seems a bit low for gain for a photo-diode. Often I see a 1 meg 1% resistor being used, which provides 1uA of bias current for the diodes. But that is just my observation.

Comment: That wire you call 'Virtual_Gnd' could be assigned a different ground symbol, thus keeping it from snaking through your schematic. An upside-down arrow symbol would work. Another option would be a unique power rail symbol.

Comment: What does do that is wrong?  Does it oscillate?  Does the output of U4 stick to one of the rails?

Comment: One of the most common differences between breadboard circuits and PCB circuits is that breadboards have a lot of capacitance between pins.

Comment: Hello everybody.Thank you for your comments.About the schematic I have to say that actually I have not design this and it has been designed by GE (GENERAL ELECTRIC) company.So. it can not bee wrong while there boards which they gave to us are working and we have tested a lot.The problem is that this design is very old and not produce any more

Comment: The original circuit may be from GE. That particular schematic, though, was drawn by someone at your company.  It is possible to make mistakes when redrawing a circuit, especially if you are working from the board rather than the original schematic diagrams.

Comment: Thank you  JRE for your answer.Actually I have drawn the schematic and I simulated my design  and after simulation I made the circuit based on my schematic on the bread board and all of them works good same as GE exactly.but, when designed and made a PCB for the circuit the problem accrued and it didn't worked good.So, I think designing the PCB should has a problem specially because of that my PCB board is 2 layers only while GE board is 4 layers and they put GND and VIRTUAL GND in to the layer 2 and 3 (middle of the board).

Comment: Now you think if I use some capacitor in my board the problem can fix or I have to design it 4 layer same as GE.(4 layers board are a little bit expansive)

Comment: You still haven't said what it does wrong when it "doesn't work."

Comment: Actually,our machine get old and as I mentioned before this board is ablated and we can not by it but, we still really need it for some of our old machine which their IR has been broken.

Comment: Right.  But what does **your** board do wrong when "it doesn't work?"

Comment: My board can not transfer any signal from remote control to the machine in the normal case, Actually when I connect my board to the machine nothing happen,I push the bottoms on the remote control and there is no respond in the machine but, as soon as I touch the photo diode pins I can see the response when I push the bottoms and our board works exactly same as the original  board.